# Angular 1.5 components default values for properties

Tags: angularjs

I am writing a component that has several properties that I want to default to a value if not supplied.

Whilst I know that I can test for the existence of these properties in the component controller like this,

```
this.foo = angular.isUndefined(this.foo) ? 'Light Blue' : this.foo;
```

I was wondering if there were a more elegant way of supplying a default value in the `binding` itself

```
.component('myComponent', {
        bindings: {
            foo: '<?Light Blue'
        },
```

or something like that

Comment: I guess `foo: '<?'` is fine, whatever you are doing inside controller is fine.. or you can `this.foo = this.foo ||  'Light Blue'`

Comment: yeah, I was just trying to make it look "nice" if I have several "optional" properties so, rather than several lines of code doing `this.x = this.x || someValue` I could just specify it on the bindings (as I've already had to specify the property name)